# How to use Safari Browser in Selenium Webdriver using Python bindings

Tags: python, selenium, safari, webdriver

I am not able to launch safari browser from Selenium web driver. I am using Python bindings. 
Could not find any reference that provided detailed steps for Python.
I am aware there is a related question on stackoverflow, but it doesn't answer for python -
[python selenium webdriver safari driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715589/python-selenium-webdriver-safari-driver)

Followed the Documentation on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver , downloaded and installed safari developer certificate. This doc has code for Java and not for python bindings.

Below is my code(I am using desired capabilities) Not sure what am I missing here -

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.SAFARI)
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you're trying to open a webpage with a webbrowser.  Why not use "webbrowser"?  It's easy to get the webbrowser have safari as default:

```
import webbrowser
browser = webbrowser.get('safari')
browser.open("http://www.google.com/")
```

As I can't selenium set up, I'm not sure if this is what you want.  Who knows, it could be an alternative?

Comment: this is not working for me. Is webbrowser library available in python bindings ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It was due to some syntax error why it didn't work earlier.

Comment: Sorry about that! It was a mistake on my part, I incorrectly closed the string.

Comment: I am using selenium web-driver setup. Would like to use Safari browser with the same setup. I overlooked the fact that this alternative doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: "webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser" is thrown

Comment: this "alternative" doesn't answer the OP's question at all